# Any Way to replace Ctrl+Shift+F Shorctut in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

This default shortcut is not human-hand friendly : As I use it a lot, it makes me have finger-cramp.
I would be glad to change it with some simpler combination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->Edit.FindInFiles` then replace the key combination.

Comment: Didn't occur to me that Edit.FindInFiles corresponded to that. ThanX

Comment: I just did a search for the word "find" and I found that entry. :)